# how to get list of product under category in vue js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Hello I'm new to vue and I have a list of json data which has a list of products under category, please how do I get to display a product under each category

Here's my json data for the category array

```
{
    "_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
    "products": [],
    "type": "mobile phone",
    "__v": 0
}
```

my product array

```
{
    "_id": "625671db370e769a8a93a510",
    "reviews": [],
    "owner": {
        "_id": "6220db7ee861f3dbbaf21e3d",
        "name": "mr jacob",
        "about": "hello",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "category": {
        "_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
        "products": [],
        "type": "mobile phone",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "title": "galaxy s21",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus ullam iusto culpa assumenda enim ea, asperiores omnis, facere quos animi doloremque, architecto facilis aut? Nobis ab sit iusto praesentium quia.",
    "photo": "https://ajibade.s3.amazonaws.com/1649832365317",
    "price": 500,
    "stockQuantity": 1,
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "625671db370e769a8a93a510"
}
```

my html template to get the list of category in my data base

```
<div class="container" v-for="category in categories" :value="category._id" :key="category._id">
      <span>{{category.type}}</span>
    </div>
```

my script tag

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Products",
  name: "categories",
  data() {
    return {
      categoryID: null,
      categories: [],
      products: [],
     
    };
  },

 
  mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products").then(res => {
      console.log(res);

      this.products = res.data.products;
    });
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/categories").then(res => {
      console.log(res);

      this.categories = res.data.categories;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Please how do I filter the products and get it under a specific category, I'm lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make inner v-for of products for category, passing `category._id` to method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      categoryID: null,
      categories: [],
      products: [],
      show: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    productsForCat(cat) {
      return this.products.filter(p => p.category._id === cat)
    },
    displayProd(id) {
      this.show === id ? this.show = null : this.show = id
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    /*axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res.data.products;*/
    //});
    this.products = [
          {"_id": "625671db370e769a8a93a510", "reviews": [], "owner": {"_id": "6220db7ee861f3dbbaf21e3d", "name": "mr jacob", "about": "hello", "__v": 0}, "category": {"_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c", "products": [], "type": "mobile phone", "__v": 0}, "title": "galaxy s21", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus ullam iusto culpa assumenda enim ea, asperiores omnis, facere quos animi doloremque, architecto facilis aut? Nobis ab sit iusto praesentium quia.", "photo": "https://ajibade.s3.amazonaws.com/1649832365317", "price": 500, "stockQuantity": 1, "__v": 0, "id": "625671db370e769a8a93a510"},
          {"_id": "625671db370e769a8a93a511", "reviews": [], "owner": {"_id": "6220db7ee861f3dbbaf21e3d", "name": "mr jacob", "about": "hello", "__v": 0}, "category": {"_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7d", "products": [], "type": "mobile phone", "__v": 0}, "title": "galaxy", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus ullam iusto culpa assumenda enim ea, asperiores omnis, facere quos animi doloremque, architecto facilis aut? Nobis ab sit iusto praesentium quia.", "photo": "https://ajibade.s3.amazonaws.com/1649832365317", "price": 500, "stockQuantity": 1, "__v": 0, "id": "625671db370e769a8a93a510"}
        ]
    /*axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/categories").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.categories = res.data.categories;*/
    //});
    this.categories = [
        {"_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c", "products": [], "type": "mobile phone", "__v": 0}, {"_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7d", "products": [], "type": "phone", "__v": 0}
      ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="container" v-for="category in categories" :key="category._id">
    <span @click="displayProd(category._id)">{{category.type}}</span>
    <div v-if="category._id === show">
      <li v-for="product in productsForCat(category._id)" :key="product._id">
        {{ product.title }}
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, this worked but i'm trying not to show the products when the browser loads , like if i click the mobile phone under category type it will display galaxy s21 , thank you

Comment: @jibzy hey mate, take a look again pls, I updated my answer (try to click on category)

Comment: please if I may ask how can I get the products in another routes, if I click on the {{category.type}}